# Reading line by line from one file and Writing to another file using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, scripting

I am trying to split a tab delemeted file into pieces with similar header. I have my logic in place. However, I am trying to read input file line by line and writing it to another file. When I open the outptut file it doesn't contain any data. Here is my code.

Can some one help me whats going wrong here?

Note: The below code doesn't contain actual logic of splitting the file

```
Wscript.Echo "Begin"
InputFile = "test.txt"
Set InputFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set InputFileObject = InputFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile)

HeaderLine = InputFileObject.ReadLine

Do While InputFileObject.AtEndOfStream <> True
    strTemp = InputFileObject.SkipLine
Loop 

TotalLines = InputFileObject.Line-1

Set OutputFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set OutputFileObject = OutputFSO.CreateTextFile("out.txt")

#Code for reading line by line and writing it to another file
Do While not InputFileObject.AtEndOfStream
    line = InputFileObject.Readline
    OutputFileObject.WriteLine(line)
Loop

Set InputFileObject = Nothing
Set OutputFileObject = Nothing
Wscript.Echo "Completed"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping through the entire input file in the first Do loop when you are trying to get the line count.  So the InputFileObject is already "AtEndOfStream" when you hit the second Do loop.  Therefore, none of the code inside the second loop is executing.

Consider eliminating the first Do loop and count the lines in the file at the end of the other loop (unless in your real program the logic in the first loop is required?).

The alternative is to close the input file and reopen it.  The problem in this case is that you'll wind up reading the file twice.

```
'Close and reopen the file from the top...
InputFileObject.Close
Set InputFileObject = InputFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have re-opened the the same file again and the file reader went to begining of the file.